# Magento 2: Get Coupon Code for Order in Order Success Observer

Tags: event-observer, magento-2.1.3, coupon-codes

I created an observer with event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`. I need applied coupon code on checkout onepage success in magento 2. I have to send order coupon code to third party with Curl. Do you know, how we can retrieve coupon code used for the order on order success page?

Here is my observer code:

```
$orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
$lastorderId = $orderIds[0];
$order = $this->orderFactory->load($lastorderId);
// echo $order->getQuoteId(); // show quote ID
// echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); // show discount amount

/* Here I need applied Coupon Code */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting the coupon code of an order, you should use

> $order->getCouponCode();

Comment: Quick Solution. Thanks @amit , its working for me.

Comment: Hi @amit,this works but how to get that amount that was applied for this coupon code in the order page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function:

> $order->getCouponCode

In `sales_order` table, there is field `coupon_code` for applied coupon code.